# printing a character when no other output was printed

Tags: c++

How do I print a particular character when up to that point in my code, no condition has been satisfied?
Example : 
If I have an array of 100 numbers and if I traverse the array by 'for' loop and do not find my number, how do I print a single line " Not Found " ?

I am using C++.

Comment: Please provide [mre], to illustrate a problem. Since it's, currently, unclear why simple `std::cout << "Not Found";` (or, rather, `if (!found) std::cout << "Not Found";`) doesn't suit your needs..

Comment: Where am I supposed to put " not found " ? At the end of the loop? But what if I do in fact find the number? It would still print " not found " wouldn't it?

Comment: "_Where am I supposed to put " not found " ?_" Wherever you want to print it. How can we tell you that, without seeing how your code looks like?

Answer (score 3):

You would typically create a boolean variable before the loop, maybe called `found` and set it to `false`. If the number is found in the loop, you would set `found` to `true`. After the loop is done, you would use an `if` statement to test if `found` is `false` and, if found to be so, output the " Not Found " message.

There are other ways that are usually better. But this is the simplest one that everyone should learn first.

Comment: ohh right ... thanks for that, I've just started to learn to code so that didn't quite click me. Thanks again.